# Combine queries in MySQL

Tags: mysql, dml

I have two table in MySQL that looks as follows:

```
ID  Name    Information
1   A       fsdf
2   B       ada
3   A       dsafd
4   A       retret
5   C       asdfsa
6   B       xzc
```

and,

```
P_ID    Name    Loc_X   Loc_Y
1       A       2       3
2       B       3       4
3       C       4       5
```

I would like to run a query in MySQL that return the result as follows:

```
NAME    COUNT   Loc_X   Loc_Y
A       3       2       3 
B       2       3       4
C       1       4       5
```

Currently, I am able to execute the following query:

```
SELECT Name,COUNT(*) as count FROM Table_A GROUP BY Name ORDER BY count DESC;
```

to get the following result:

```
NAME    COUNT
A       3
B       2
C       1
```

I know that probably I can use this result to extract only the "Name" and fire another query to get the Loc_X and Loc_Y using PHP, but I was wondering whether there is a moe efficient way of doing it using DML. Is there a way to nest the queries?

Comment: tried inner join? `SELECT a.Name,Count(*) as count,b.Loc_X,b.Loc_Y FROM Table_A a INNER JOIN Table_B ON a.Name = b.Name ORDER BY count DESC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
SELECT Table_A.Name,COUNT(*) as count, Table_B.Loc_X, Table_B.Loc_Y
FROM Table_A 
INNER JOIN Table_B ON Table_A.name = Table_B.name
GROUP BY Table_A.Name, Table_B.Loc_X, Table_B.Loc_Y 
ORDER BY count DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to join the tables on the common field here.

Try:

```
SELECT a.Name, count(a.id) AS Count b.Loc_X, b.Loc_Y
FROM Table_A a
INNER JOIN Table_B b ON a.Name = b.Name
GROUP BY a.Name
```